# Spotify post request throws me "invalid credentials" error despite it being correct

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to do a POST request to log-into Spotify. However, despite my username and password being correct, it tells me that it's invalid.

I've tried changing my payload a bit but nothing that will work.

```
def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url
    self.session = requests.session()

def login(self, username, password):
    payload = {'remember': True, 'username': username, 'password': password}
    dest = self.session.post(url=self.url, data=payload)
    self.session.close()
```

Login url:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/password/login
```

Here's the post-data:

```
remember=
username=
password=wewe
recaptchaToken=-
csrf_token=
```

I did not know what to put as recaptchaToken nor `csrf_token` so I didn't include those.

I expected a succesful login but got this instead:

```
{"error":"errorInvalidCredentials"}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add headers from your browser?

Comment: nop, I will try that now, what would I set as my header?

Comment: Spotify is using reCaptcha, in order to protect its website against bots/scripts (hence the `recaptchaToken` variables). Which makes it practically impossible for you to login using purely the `requests` library. That being said, your best bet would be to use some captcha solving websites (which are all paid), the most popular being http://2captcha.com.

Comment: @Fozoro is there a way to post login without using a captcha solving site? e.g use proxies etc.

Comment: I’m pretty sure there isn’t. Using a proxy will just change the location of where you are accessing the site, it won’t affect on how the site was built.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use API logins rather than main login page. That `csrf_token` is necessary and you need to take it first by capturing it from main page cookies, then include cookies in your header.

If you don't want to take multiple redirects you can use headless browsers such as `phantomjs` , `googledriver` and `firefoxdriver`

I have seen many changes in Spotify so make sure your code is up to date.